# When i click the button i don't get right position of FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

i came here today because, when i press a button, i dont get the right position of data in recycler view;

```
      ...
   FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<usertasks,PrivateTasksViewHolder> 
 TasksRecyclerViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<usertasks, 
PrivateTasksViewHolder>(options){
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public PrivateTasksViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            return new PrivateTasksViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_view, viewGroup, false));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PrivateTasksViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final usertasks model) {


            final String list_task_id = getRef(position).getKey();
            mTasksDatabase.push().child(list_task_id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    holder.setTaskName(model.getTaskname());
                    holder.setTaskLocal(model.getTasklocal());
                    holder.setTaskDate(model.getTaskdate());
                    ImageView thrash_delete = mMainView.findViewById(R.id.thrash_delete);
                        thrash_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Map deletePrivateTask = new HashMap();
                                deletePrivateTask.put("PrivateTasks/" + mCurrent_user_id + "/" + list_task_id , null);
                                mRootRef.updateChildren(deletePrivateTask);
                            }
                        });
 ...
```

But when is holder he get the right position.
Someone know the reason of the problem, why i cant get the tight positions when ImageView is clicked? And why when it´s holder it get the right position?

```
 holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
  Map deletePrivateTask = new HashMap();
  deletePrivateTask.put("PrivateTasks/" + mCurrent_user_id + "/" + list_task_id , null);
   mRootRef.updateChildren(deletePrivateTask);
 }});
```

Hope you guys can give me some tips, thank you all.
I keep search the solution, but i didnt find any solution at now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of position use:

```
holder.getAdapterPosition()
```

You can read more details [here](https://medium.com/@noureldeen.abouelkassem/difference-between-position-getadapterposition-and-getlayoutposition-in-recyclerview-80279a2711d1).

Comment: I will try this mate, i came here later to inform if it works. :)

Comment: Didn´t work :(, i have to get the positio of data, that i receive from database...